# How to send WebRequest via proxy?

Tags: .net, proxy, httpwebrequest, port

How does the following code need to be modified to send the `WebRequest` via a specified `proxy server` and `port number`?

```
Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
Request.Method = "POST"
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Request.GetRequestStream())
    writer.Write(params)
End Using
```

Answer (score 7):

use this code from MSDN :

```
Dim myProxy As New WebProxy()
myProxy.Address = New Uri("proxyAddress")
myProxy.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
myWebRequest.Proxy = myProxy
```

Answer (score 4):

A WebRequest object has a 'Proxy' property of IWebProxy. You should be able to assign it to use a specified proxy.

```
Request.Proxy = New WebProxy("http://myproxy.com:8080");
```

If the proxy is not anonymous, you will need to specify the Credentials of the WebProxy object.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if your Web server needs to go through the proxy server at `http://255.255.1.1:8080`,

```
Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
 'Create the proxy class instance
Dim prxy as New WebProxy("http://255.255.1.1:8080")

 'Specify that the HttpWebRequest should use the proxy server
Request .Proxy = prxy

Request.Method = "POST"
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Request.GetRequestStream())
writer.Write(params)
End Using
```