# Not able to access a page from US as a country

Tags: c#

I want to use the US as a country to access this 
url = http://www.tillys.com/product/Say-What/Short-Dresses/SAY-WHAT--Ribbed-Tank-Midi-Dress/Heather-Grey/285111595, 
I've tried with cookies and all but the url still it redirects to the site's home page.
I want to see if there is any way i can access this page. Below is the code with which i am trying.

Below is the function with which i am trying to do this:

```
    public static string getUrlContent (string url)
    {

        var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;
        myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
        myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", "=en%5FUS;");
        myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/49.0.2623.108 Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Safari/537.36";
        //myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
        myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", "wlcme=true");
        //myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        //myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Macys-ClientId", "NavApp");
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var rmyResponseHeaders = response.Headers;
        Console.WriteLine ("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
        Console.WriteLine ("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType);

        // Get the stream associated with the response.
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        //Console.WriteLine ("Response stream received.");
        Console.WriteLine (readStream.ReadToEnd ());
        var josnStr = readStream.ReadToEnd ();
        Console.WriteLine (josnStr);
        return josnStr;
        //Encoding enc1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

    }
```

Comment: This is something you can't solve on protocol level directly. You'll need a proxy or VPN to connect to to retrieve the file or webpage for you (and then forward it)

Comment: okay, thanks, i will try setting up a VPN and make the web request.

Answer (score 2):

If the site `www.tillys.com` is using [Geo-fencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-fence) it will show you different content based on a lookup of the requesting IP address.  In this case there's nothing C# or other languages can do.

You'll need to either proxy your request through a VPN (see [How to send WebRequest via proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447495/how-to-send-webrequest-via-proxy)) or deploy your code to a data center in the US.  For example, if you use Azure you can deploy to several different data centers through out the world including several data centers in the US.  Once your code is running in the US it should be able to access the US version of the page.